# Restricting certain public APIs/classes to users in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, securitymanager, java-security-manager

I have a application where users can write their customizations using the exposed public APIs.
There are few public classes and API that are public but we don't want them to be accessible in the customization code for the users.
Is there any way in java to do this without changing the access modifiers of the remaining APIs.
I am exploring java security manager, don't know if it would work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: whitout any explanation on how you expose the API and classes, it is hardly answerable

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers

Comment: In particular, *"**Default:** The access level of a default modifier is only within the package. It cannot be accessed from outside the package. If you do not specify any access level, it will be the default."*

Comment: The answer to "Is there any way in java to do this without changing the access modifiers of the remaining APIs" is "No."

Comment: And even using access modifiers is no guarantee, given the existence of reflection.  But it doesn't matter; "package private" is good enough for most purposes.   Bite the bullet and use proper access modifiers.

Comment: Modules could help. Packages not exported are not accessible by other modules.

Comment: Restricting user-submitted code is notoriously hard in Java in the presence of reflection APIs. Here is a relevant paper we wrote last year that might be of interest: https://www.sazzadur.com/pdfs/SecureDL.pdf